# How to convert JSON array property value from arrays to keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am a beginner programmer trying to convert JSON array property value from arrays to keys.
From

`..,"searchResult":[{"itemId":["123"],"title":["abc"],..}]`
to

`..,"searchResult":[{"itemId":"123","title":"abc",..}]`

Full original JSON result here with search result highlighted

[image: Full original JSON result here]

the JSON array is being received in  this code

```
//function to retrieve JSON arrays
function _cb_findItemsByKeywords(root) {
//Navigates and assigns variable "items" into the property, item
  var items = root.findItemsByKeywordsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item || []; 
  var a = (items);
  //assigned variable a to the array
}
```

Question: How do I remove the square brackets and check my array a?

EDIT:
Sorry for the confusion, My goal is to combine this array with `[..]` with another array without `[..]` before appending the properties to a table.
My plan:[image]

Comment: What do you want to set these keys to? It's not valid JSON to just have keys. What are you trying to accomplish

Comment: `{"123"}` does not make sense

Comment: You mean "how to convert a JSON array to an object"?

Comment: you are right @pointy, changed it

Comment: Well `{123}` doesn't make any more sense than `{"123"}`.

Comment: Please see that the response you get is a array of objects, that can contain properties with an array in it. Maybe you can explain what your goal of converting the json is. The square brackets mean that it is an array you print.

Comment: `"searchResult":[{"itemId":{"123"},"title":{"abc"},..}]` is not a valid json format

Comment: I think You want to check `if(itemId['123'])` so why just not make it like: `if(itemId.indexOf('123') > -1)` ?

Comment: What Pointy is leaving out that seems to be tripping you up - the *reason* `{"123"}` or `{123}` makes no sense is that a key must have a value.  `{"123": "something goes here"}` ...

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you wish to convert a JSON array into a Javascript object, since altering JSON property values to keys wouldn't be valid JSON.

To convert JSON array into Javascript object, in pure Javascript you do:

`JSON.parse(yourJSONgoeshere);`

Docs and examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Hope it helps.